# UWP Visibility hide when splitviewpane is collapsed

Tags: xamarin, uwp, mvvmcross, splitview

Is it possible to navigate to the parent element from a frame?
To make my answer a little bit more clear.

I have a SplitView with 2 frames
Frame 1 is menu
Frame 2 is content
When click on menuitem frame 2 will be reloaded with the new content.

In Frame 1 I have the menuitems (clickable) and a ListViewItem which is my app text, If my pane is in compact mode, I want to hide the text.

I tried with:

- { Binding IsPaneOpen, ElementName=RootSplitView, Converter=... }
- { Binding ElementName=RootSplitView, Path=IsPaneOpen, Converter=... }
- { Binding IsPaneOpen, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, ElementName=RootSplitView, Converter=... }

In all cases I see the option IsElementBinded = false.

Using: MvvmCross, Xamarin

Anyone a solution / idea?

**Update**
I tried for example this:

```
<TextBlock x:Name="MenuHeaderBlock" 
FontWeight="Bold" 
FontSize="25" 
Text="{Binding Title}" 
Visibility="{Binding IsPaneOpen, ElementName=RootSplitView, Mode=TwoWay, Converter={StaticResource BoolToVisibilityConverter}}" 
TextAlignment="Center" 
TextWrapping="NoWrap" 
Foreground="White"/>
```

Comment: If you want to hide text, just make converter from bool to visibility and use binding to the `IsPaneOpen` property and use `Converter="<key of your bool to visibility converter>"`

Comment: Try setting the mode of the binding. Either Mode=OneWay or Mode=TwoWay. Should need TwoWay, but worth a try

Comment: @m.rogalski as you can see I just work with the converter, but my problem is that the live property viewer shows me that the bind is not correct. What I want is from the frame to the splitview (parent) and based on that.

Comment: @ShawnKendrot Mode is not the problem (yet) but the way I can bind the frame (child) with an element of the SplitView (parent)

Comment: Can you supply some XAML